# TestNG @Factory Priority

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

Is there a way to put a priority on a `@Factory` method? I've tried `@AfterMethod`, `@AfterTest`, and `@AfterClass`, all result in my factory method running immediately after my setup call with the `@BeforeClass` tag.

My code is similar to this:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Test()
    public void method1() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "method1")
    public void method2() {

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "method2")
    public void method3() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "method3")
    public void method4() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "method4")
    public void method5() throws Exception {

    }

    @AfterClass
    @Factory
    public Object[] factory() {
        Object[] values = new Object[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = new validationFactory(map.get(i).x, map.get(i).y);
        }
        return values;
    }
```

What the code is doing is reaching out to an API, retrieving any requested data, slicing that data up into a `map`, and then passing that map of data into the factory method in order to validate it. The problem is that immediately after my setup method runs, the factory shoots off and validates an empty map. Is there any way to make the factory method wait until the data is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `@Factory` is to [create tests dynamically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories). It doesn't make sense to run those tests after an `@AfterClass` method, so even if you could work around your problem by checking if the map was empty (so that `factory()` runs twice, but the loop - only once), any tests created by the factory would not be executed by the framework.

If what you need is to validate some data after all the tests have finished, put that validation in a method annotated with `@AfterClass` (without `@Factory`). You can use assertions there as in a regular test.

If for some reason you want to run the validation as separate tests and have to use a factory, there is a way to defer their execution until after the other tests, but they still have to be instantiated at the beginning. So it looks like you need to pass some object that would load the data when required instead of initializing the validation tests with map entries right away. A data provider may work, but here's a simpler example.

Add all the main tests to a group.

```java
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "method1", groups = "Main")
public void method2() { }
```

Create a class or a method that will load the data when needed, it depends on how you populate the map. It has to be thread-safe because TestNG runs tests in parallel. A very simplistic implementation:

```java
public class DataLoader {

    // Location has data members X and Y
    private Map<Integer, Location> locations;

    public synchronized Location getLocation(int index) {

        if (locations == null) {
            locations = new HashMap<>();
            // load the map
        }

        return locations.get(index);
    }
}
```

Create a class to represent a validation test. Notice its only test depends on the main group.

```java
public class ValidationTest {

    private int index;
    private DataLoader loader;

    public ValidationTest(int index, DataLoader loader) {
        this.number = number;
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = "Main")
    public void validate() {
        Location location = this.loader.getLocation(this.index);
        // do whatever with location.x and location.y
    }
}
```

Instantiate the validation tests. They will run after the main group has finished. Notice I have removed the `@AfterClass` annotation.

```java
@Factory
public Object[] factory() {

    DataLoader loader = new DataLoader();
    Object[] validators = new Object[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
        validators[i] = new ValidationTest(i, loader);
    }

    return validators;
}
```

*By the way, dependencies between test methods indicate poorly written tests, and should be avoided, at least for unit-tests. There are frameworks other than TestNG for testing complex scenarios.*

Comment: Your solution works perfectly in a small scale test I set up, but how would you scale up the size of the `Object[]`? As it needs to be dynamically size because the data I get back could be 1 or 10,000 entries. As for the dependencies, if you got tips on how to improve on them, it'd be greatly appreciated. As it stands now, I don't want my validate method to run before there's any data to validate, and I don't want my file processing test to run before the API sends me the file/data.

Comment: My solution was based on your example, where the size of `values` is known. As I told you, dynamic tests can run after the rest have finished, but they must be initialized at the beginning. Use a test method that runs last, or an `@AfterClass` method for validation. Factory will not work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I can work around the array length.

Answer (score 0):

A TestNG run has 2 distinct phases:

1. Creation of tests ;
2. Run of tests.

Then, you can expect to create some new tests during the run of tests.